# Manipulate with DSolve and Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I try to draw a graph:

```
     ClearAll[k, r, n]
    k = 20
    r = .8

    Manipulate[
     psol = DSolve[{p'[t] == r*p[t] (1 - p[t]/k), p[0] == n}, p[t], t];
     Plot[ psol[t] , {t, -10, 10} ], {n, 0, 1}]
```

but I get an error:

> Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Answer (score 1):

The message is warning that `inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found`

You can ignore it if you want

```
ClearAll[k, r, n]
k = 20
r = .8
Manipulate[
 psol=Quiet[DSolve[{p'[t]==r*p[t] (1-p[t]/k),p[0]==n},p[t],t]];
 Plot[p[t]/.psol,{t,-10,10}],
 {{n,0,"n"},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"}
]
```

Or it might be better to turn off that one messaage

```
Manipulate[
  psol=DSolve[{p'[t]==r*p[t] (1-p[t]/k),p[0]==n},p[t],t];
  Plot[p[t]/.psol,{t,-10,10}],{{n,0,"n"},0,1,Appearance->"Labeled"}
,Initialization:>
{
  k=20;
  r=.8;
  Off[Solve::ifun]
}
]
```

[image]

see `ref/message/Solve/ifun` for more information on this message

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can still use `Quiet[]` to turn off a single message locally: `Quiet[Solve[y == x Exp[x], x], Solve::ifun]`.

Comment: If plotting the solution is the only goal, you could just use `NDSolve`.

Comment: Rather than repeatedly evaluating `DSolve`, move that to the `Initialization`: `Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[n, t], {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 20}], {{n, 0}, 0, 1, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Initialization :> {k = 20;
   r = 4/5;
   sol[n_, t_] = 
    p[t] /. DSolve[{p'[t] == r*p[t] (1 - p[t]/k), p[0] == n}, p, 
        t][[1]] // Quiet}]`